# java - parsing an aspx website - post parameters

Tags: java, asp.net, html-parsing, http-post

I have my client's e-shop, which is created by another company. I want to parse all the products and put them in an xml. I know how to get to the first page of each "brand" but I have difficulties passing the argument to change the page for the paginated results.

This is the e-shop "http://www.gialia.net.gr/ProductCatalog/20/CAR.aspx" that points to one brand.

When I user tamper-data on firefox I see that when you want to press the second-page of the results is posts the :

```
"__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24wpmMain%24wp131820866%24wp512420601%24dpgTop%24ctl01%24ctl01"
```

the last string: "ct101" means go to page 2, If I change it to ct102 it goes to page 3 etc.

BUT i'm trying to create it as a GET request so I can create these parameters dynamically in my Java code and parse each responce. But when I create the url as:

```
http://www.gialia.net.gr/ProductCatalog/20/CAR.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$wpmMain$wp131820866$wp512420601$dpgTop$ctl01$ctl02
```

I get no results.

Can someone please take a look and give me some suggestions?

Comment: Use Apache HttpClient, with that library you can create POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

The site you give us here is very poor in design concerning the search engines (SEO), and so the parse of the page one by one is too difficult.

To change page is make post back, and with javascript only. So you must do the same to move to the next page of the catalog, you need to make a full post back of the page with all the parameters.

Now, the page is so bad designed that the programmer have disable the `__EVENTVALIDATION` of the controls probably because he not let him do wrong things, so when you can tamper the data, but still you need to make post back. By simple type on the url one only parametre the code behind did not understand that is post back. You need to send and at least the Viewstate and the rest hidden parameters.

But isn't more easy to just get from your client access direct to the database and reads them from there ?